# Incorrect reshaping of 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am doing some processing with a matrix of shape 1536 x 16 x 48. Here are some details about this dimensions:

- 1536: data collected in 6 seconds
- 16: number of collectors (or electrodes in my case)
- 48: number of samples

So, i have 48 samples of 1536 values (representing 6 seconds of data) from the perspective of 16 different collectors.

My goal is to do some processing with this matrix, but to do so some transformations are needed first.

1. Since 6 seconds is a large sequence, i want to split each of those samples into smaller sequences, specially 3 or 2 seconds. For instance, 1 sample of 6 seconds (1536) can be split into 2 samples of 3 seconds (768) or 3 samples of 2 seconds (512). The shape of this transformed matrix would go from `1536x16x48` to `768x16x96` (for 3 seconds) or `512x16x144` (for 2 seconds).
2. Once i have this new matrix, i want to reshape it so i get one 2d matrix per observer and all values organized in columns instead of rows (e.g. for 2 seconds split: `512x16x144` => `144x512x16`).
3. Finally, i can now loop through 3rd dimension (`16`), do some computations (i.e. fast fourier transform) with each 2d matrix and reduce (sum) them all into a single one to get a final `144 x 512` matrix (in 2 seconds-split scenario).

The following code is what i made with `numpy`, but it is clearly wrong for me when i plot samples generated from this method.

```py
def generate_fft_data(data,labels, n_seconds_split=3):
    x = 256 * n_seconds_split
    y = 16
    z = 48 * int(6/n_seconds_split)
    data = data.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(x,y,z).transpose(2,0,1)
    fft_data = []
    for electrode in range(data.shape[2]):
        y_t = fft(data[:,:,electrode])
        fft_data.append(np.abs(y_t))
    sum_of_ffts = np.add.reduce(fft_data) 
    return sum_of_ffts
```

I can provide more details if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a great use-case for [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the hardest part for me now is (believe it or not) the reshaping/splitting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def generate_fft_data(data,n_seconds_split=3):
    x_split = 6//n_seconds_split
    # split along 0 axis, stack pieces along the last axis and transpose
    arr = np.dstack(np.split(data, x_split)).transpose(2,0,1)
    fft_data = []
    for electrode in range(arr.shape[2]):
        y_t = fft(arr[:,:,electrode])
        fft_data.append(np.abs(y_t))
    sum_of_ffts = np.add.reduce(fft_data) 
    return sum_of_ffts
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a remark: in your case, `n_seconds_split` doesn't represent the length of the desired sample, but the divisor that will split original samples instead (e.g. `n_seconds_split=3` means samples with size `6/3 = 2`)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [88]: data = np.ones((1536,16,48))
In [89]:  x = 256 * 3
    ...:  y = 16
    ...:  z = 48 * int(6/3)
In [90]: x,y,z
Out[90]: (768, 16, 96)
In [91]: data.transpose(2,0,1).shape
Out[91]: (48, 1536, 16)
In [92]: data.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(x,y,z).shape
Out[92]: (768, 16, 96)
```

Reshaping [91] to [92] does not make sense.  It works because the numbers 'add' up, but the distribution is messed up.

I think you want to first split the 1536 dimension into (2,768) (or the 3 equivalent), then move that 2 dimension to the end, and recombine it with the 48.

The details could vary, but here's one such sequence:

```
data1 = data.reshape(2,768,16,48).transpose(1,2,0,3).reshape(768,16,96)
```